# new with less, require is undefined

Tags: less

Here is my setup

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.1.0/less.min.js"></script>




    var less = require('less');
    less.render(less_str,
        {
            paths: ['.', './lib'],  // Specify search paths for @import directives
            filename: 'style.less', // Specify a filename, for better error messages
            compress: false          // Minify CSS output
        },
        function (e, output) {
            alert(output.css);
        }
    );
```

the browser throw an error: require is undefined

Comment: This code snippet of the documentation is for programmatic use of the Less compiler in the `node` environment. For the in-browser usage see [Using Less in the Browser](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) (you don't normally need any `require` and `render` at all there).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445979/how-to-use-less-mixins-file-in-my-code/27453018 for a working example