# how to use less mixins file in my code?

Tags: less

here is my code

```
var parser = window.less.Parser();
        try{
            parser.parse(aztp_css_editor.getValue(), function(error, result){
                if(!error){
                    alert(result.toCSS());
                }else{
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }catch(error){
            alert(error);
        }
```

I have a mixins less file here http://lessprefixer.com/ for shorthand css3 prefix, how I setup it into my parse less code?

Comment: Less libraries are "set up" in your Less code (via [`@import` directive](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-directives-feature)) not in your JavaScript code. Also for vendor prefixing instead of mixins libraries use `Autoprefixer` (if you compile your Less files in `node`) or `-prefix-free` (if you compile your Less files in browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should better the `less.render` function, see also: http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage.

But indeed you can use the @import directive as already made clear by @seven-phases-max.

Example:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.1.0/less.min.js"></script>
<script>
less.render('@import "test.less"; p {color: @red; }', {'include-path': 'test/'})
    .then(function(output) {
        // output.css = string of css
        // output.map = string of sourcemap
        // output.imports = array of string filenames of the imports referenced
        console.log(output.css);
    },
    function(error) {
    });
</script>
```

The above compiles well (results in `output.css`) when test.less is available in the same path as the html which contains the code. You can also use a path in your import, `'@import "path/test.less";` I did not found that setting include-path has any effect.